# Consuming Wcf from Android , bad request error

Tags: android

Im trying to consume Wcf from Android , my code

```
private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://188.59.2.211:8081/Survey.svc";

String email = "xx@gmail.com";
String password = "123";

public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Login(email,password);
    }

private void Login(String email, String password)
    {
        try {

        URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URI + "/Login/email="+email+"&password="+password);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(request);
            if ( response != null )
            {
              Log.i( "login", "received " + response.toString());
            }
            else
            {
              Log.i( "login", "got a null response" );
            }

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the wcf service side,

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://saas.com")]
public interface ISurvey
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
       UriTemplate = "/Login/email={email}&password={password}",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    LoginResult Login(string email, string password);
}
```

and my config,

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="httpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="SAASService.Survey">
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="SAASService.ISurvey" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The problem is that, Im using the below url,

"http://188.59.2.211:8081/Survey.svc/Login/email=xx@gmail.com&password=123"

and it is always  giving "Bad Request" error , statusCode = 400

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a web service like that from Android won't work. Also, SOAP is xml, not json, so your content type is wrong.

To consume web services in Android, it's best to use the [ksoap-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library.
You can check [this tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) for sample code.

Here is a sample code that I used in one of my recent projects.

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://webService.protocols.users.mydomain.com/";
private static final String URL = "http://1.1.1.1/domain/ws/userServices?wsdl";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";

public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    String METHOD_NAME = "authenticate";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("arg0", username);
    request.addProperty("arg1", password);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    SoapObject result = null;
    try {
        result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
        return false;
    }

    // anything below this line relates to the service return type, may not apply to you
    boolean success = Boolean.valueOf(result.getProperty("success").toString());
    if (success)
        sessionId.set(result.getProperty("sessionId").toString());
    else
        error_message.set(result.getProperty("errorMessage").toString());

    return success;
}
```